# Trying to compile a .a library file from ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, ecslidingviewcontroller

I think my problem is due to my lack of knowledge with native iOS development. I am working on a Xamarin project and wanted to create a native binding to the  ECSlidingViewController library. To do that I need it as a static library (.a file).

I checked out the source on Github and installed cocoapods. I can compile and run the example projects just fine. Under the Pods project I can see that there are several .a files as products. But I'm not able to find the actual files.

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I managed to ceate the .a file by creating a new iOS static library project and importing the source manually, then compiling it.